# Passing Procedure Parameters of Variables to Child Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I was reading the 70-461 TSQL training book and the part about stored procedures said this...

"Variables declared in Proc1 and Proc1's parameters are not visible to any of the procedures called by Proc1"

But in the same book was this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sales.ListCustomerByAddress
(@address AS NVARCHAR(60))
AS
DECLARE @SQLString AS NVARCHAR(4000);
SET @SQLString = '
SELECT companyname, contactname
FROM Sales.Customers WHERE address = @address';

EXECUTE sp_executesql
         @statement = @SQLString,
         @params = N'@address NVARCHAR(60)',
         @address = @address;
RETURN;  
GO
```

My understanding of the quoted statement is that the `@SQLString` variable and `@address` parameter cannot be visible to and referenced by the `sp_executesql` procedure? A variable is an object that holds a value so If it is not there or cannot be seen (for instance in `@statement =` ) how can the value be used or passed

Can someone help reconcile this contradiction?

Comment: you can pass a var into a sub proc. but a sub proc does not automatically see variables from above

Comment: Thank you @juergend, my thoughts exactly. I knew that statement was erroneous.

Comment: It's technically not erroneous, just poorly phrased. They aren't visible... Unless you make them visible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What they were trying to say is you can't reference a variable or parameter that was defined in the parent procedure within the child procedure.

So the procedure (parent):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sales.ListCustomerByAddress
(@address AS NVARCHAR(60))
AS
DECLARE @SQLString AS NVARCHAR(4000);
SET @SQLString = '
SELECT companyname, contactname
FROM Sales.Customers WHERE address = @address';

EXECUTE sp_CustomExecSQL
RETURN;  
GO
```

Then the child procedure sp_CustomExecSQL could not reference @SQLString like below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sales.sp_CustomExecSQL
as
Exec(@SQLString)
GO
```

But as you showed in your example, you can pass a variable or parameter from the parent procedure into the parameter of the child procedure